# Is pronoun switching on the fly a thing?

Tags: song-lyrics, pronouns

There's a song called Ame no Musique for the game Symphonic Rain. 
The song's sung by a character that uses 私｛わたし｝when she speaks, but in the song there's a line that uses あたし:

アタシヲアイシテ

And then the next line goes to 私...

だれも知らない私が　ここにいるのよ

Could someone help me understand why two different pronouns might be used in this song? Is あたし supposed to relatable to listeners of the song, then 私 referring to the singer herself?

Also in general, other than for politeness like switching from 俺　to 私 or switching pronouns as you get older, do people switch personal pronouns for any other reasons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, あたし sounds casual or childish as compared to わたし. Unlike わたし, you should not use あたし in business settings.

アタシヲアイシテ is written in katakana, which implies this particular line belongs to a different context. Have you ever seen an all-katakana sentence like this said by a yandere character or someone in a fury? In this case, アタシヲアイシテ represents her hidden but strong feelings, and that's why she (Falsita) temporarily switched from 私 to アタシ.

Similarly, a male character who normally uses 僕 may temporarily switch to 俺 when he is excited or angry. Changing a first-person pronoun is one of the ways to show one's emotion.

Comment: That makes sense what you said about katakana sentences.. I see those a lot in songs

Answer (score 2):

Specific explanation might be serious spoiler of the great scenario of that game, so I answer in a abstract way intentional, sorry.
It seems like there are two points to switch pronounce.

- People know only アタシ, which she(わたし) is just performing, so nobody knows her bare naked face. To emphasize the difference, switching a little.
- For the RHYME. Top note sounds similar to アタシ rather than わたし.
  　[L]ook__me [L]isten__me
  　[A]tashi__[Ai]shite...